# Questions on jquery DatePicker

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a couple of simple questions on DatePicker...

Is it possible for me to select a time along with my date?  How can I do that?

I need to make sure my user can not pick a date that happens before a certain time, and I also need to make sure that the user can select dates further back in history that is the norm...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the date picker is specifically for dates, no times. You can always build one separately. Just Google it. Also, what do you mean by a date before a certain time? Why not just limit the dates minDate and maxDate options?

Comment: Can you believe I have asked all my questions for this month?